# How to merge 2 xml and list unique elements?

Tags: xml, list, merge

We need to merge 2 large xml files and list one unique element like IP address,
The uniqueness comes from the tag name, status and type.

Input File 1:-

```
- <network>
- <node>
  <id>11</id> 
  <name>aaa.com</name> 
  <status>active</status> 
  <ip>1.1.1.1</ip> 
  <type>Windows</type>
  </node>
- <node>
  <id>12</id> 
  <name>bbb.com</name> 
  <status>active</status> 
  <ip>2.2.2.2</ip> 
  <type>Unix</type>
  </node>
```

Input File 2:-

```
- <network>
- <node>
  <id>21</id> 
  <name>aaa.com</name> 
  <status>active</status> 
  <ip>1.1.1.1</ip> 
  <type>Windows</type>
  </node>
- <node>
  <id>22</id> 
  <name>ccc.com</name> 
  <status>active</status> 
  <ip>3.3.3.3</ip> 
  <type>Unix</type>
  </node>
  </network>
```

=============
The output has to be the list of active IP addresses based on type

Something like:

```
Windows.txt
1.1.1.1

Unix.txt
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Comment: What tools are available to you? What have you tried? SO is not a free "write code for me" service, it's a "help me work through a coding problem I'm having" forum. (Although even if someone wanted to write code for you, you haven't even said what platform you're running!)

Comment: What language do you want to use for this? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)